# Performing Survival Analysis on the same data, different tests - one rejects but the other one doesn't

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science

Here's a link to the dataset I'm investigating:
  https://github.com/kaizhang/dataset/blob/master/data/survival/leukemia.csv

I want to test for statistical significance in the differences between maintained group vs non-maintained group in a survival analysis. Here's the Kaplan-Meier plot showing the distribution of the probability of an event occurring for the two groups. One can clearly observe that, on average, the subjects in the maintained group will survive longer than the ones in the unmaintained group. 
[image]

The statistical test log-rank validates this finding:

```
# Apply log-rank test 

from lifelines.statistics import logrank_test

results = logrank_test(t[maintained],t[~maintained],s[maintained],t[~maintained], alpha=0.99)
results.print_summary()
```

[image]

The result shows that there's a statistical significance in the differences of survival time among the two groups. So, I'm assuming that when tested for log-hazards, I should expect to see statistical differences in there. In other words, log-hazards for the maintaineed group (x=1) should be lower than the unmaintained group (x=0). To test this, I fitted a cox regression model:

```
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter

df = data.copy()
df.x.replace(['Maintained', 'Nonmaintained'], [1,0], inplace=True)

cf = CoxPHFitter()
cf.fit(df.ix[:,1:], 'time', event_col='status')
cf.print_summary()
```

[image]

What's bizarre is that in this test, there is no statistical significance in the parameter estimate of x ( maintained ), meaning that the log hazards of maintained and unmaintained are not different.

**1) In an event such as this show a discrepency in statistical test results, how should a statistician approach interpret survival in relations to different effects?**

**2) Could the cox-regression be unreliable since the sample size is less than 30?**

Comment: This question is not appropriate on SO, which is a forum for focused questions on programming problems. Please remove this question and ask it on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or maybe data science SE.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your call to the log rank test: `results = logrank_test(t[maintained],t[~maintained],s[maintained],t[~maintained], alpha=0.99)
` - you are calling `t[~maintained]` twice.